# Pointing to customized address

Tags: c, pointers

I have weird question. Consider having the following code:

```
char *ptr = 'A';
```

ptr will point to the address 0x41. I know you can't just dereference this pointer.
How would one make a similar code that would make ptr point to the address which is made by string?
For example, if we have the string "abc", then the address that ptr will point to is the value of that string.
This isn't what i'm looking for:

```
char *ptr = "abc"
```

since it will make ptr point memory where the string abc is located.

What will be the longest length of that string that we will be able to make (on 32 bit machine)

Comment: What do you mean by "value of the string"? What is the value of `"HELLO"` for instance?

Comment: Please rephrase your question I don't understand what you need

Comment: Does `char *ptr = 'A'` really compile?

Comment: @Wolf GCC only emits a warning : `initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]`.

Comment: Ok, [there is my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31605684/2932052) to this weird question: compiles without warning and does the job.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* wish to set the `ptr` value to a bit pattern of the data that a string literal represents (using four 4 chars for 4 bytes on a 32 machine), than this is what you have to write:

```
char *ptr = *((char**)"abcd");
```

BTW: The pointer type is absolutely irrelevant for "the trick"

```
int *ptr2 = *(int**)"abcd";
```

Short Explanation: String literals like `"abcd"` are syntactically treated as `char` pointers (or `const char` pointers). The contents of a pointer can be dereferenced with the `*` operator. You need to convince the compiler to dereference an 32 bit entity, and a pointer is such an 32 bit entity on a 32-bit memory model. Even a 32-bit value could be used to get the pattern that is represented by a string literal build from 4-ASCII-chars, you only need to make the compiler treat the literal as an `int` (on a 32-bit operand machine), this also looks much cleaner:

```
int s2i = *(int*)"ABCD"; // 0x64636261 on a Little Endian architecture
```

...and there is another trick, that is seems to be some compilers:

```
int c2i = ((int)'ABCD'); // 0x61626364 on a Little Endian architecture
```

Answer (score -1):

Well when you do

```
char *ptr = 'A';
```

You're effectively just doing

```
char *ptr = 65;
```

However, I don't understand what you meant by "address created by string".

To get higher values, you can use number:

```
char *ptr = 13213;
```

(No idea why you would want to do that though)

Comment: I meant that the address ptr points to, is the value of a certain string.
I just found out how (it's really simple, I don't know why I didn't think about it before):
    
    char *ptr = (int)("hello");

Comment: I absolutely do not get what you're trying to do. This will do something, but WHY YOU WANT IT???

Comment: I don't really need it, it won't actually work, i'm just trying to see...
@Mat - if i'd do char *ptr = "hello" , it'd create a string "hello", and ptr will point to it. In my case, I want that the address ptr has, would be the int value of an string (like I did the int value of an char).

Comment: @user3604597 Do you mean something like `char* ptr = (char*)(uint32_t)*"abcd";`?  Reinterpret the bits of the string as the address of a pointer?

Comment: @user3604597 `char *ptr = (int)("hello");` will cast the address of string literal in the literal pool into integer and asign it to `ptr` (see my answer). I don't see any use case of this. Do you want to be able to change the value of string literal? You shoud never do this because string literals are constant, trying to change value of a string literal invokes UB.

Comment: @Namfuak - Yes, that what I meant, but your code will make the address ptr points to 61 (the value of a)...
vasicbre - There is no actually reason to use this, I was just wondering how to make the address of a pointer be the int value of a string...

Comment: @user3604597 Huh, I suppose it would.  You could create an integer of appropriate size with all 0s and `|` each letter in the appropriate spot.

Comment: @user3604597 `char *ptr = (int)("hello");` assigns the address of the first character of the string literal to `ptr`; if `sizeof(int) == sizeof(char *)` on your system, it's exactly the same as `char *ptr = "hello";` (except that it does a prohibited implicit conversion from pointer to integer).

Answer (score -1):

The equivalent to `char *ptr = 'A'` with what you call a string would be like `char *ptr = 'ABCD'`. The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character is implementation-defined.

`char *ptr = (int)("hello")` is **not** what you are looking for, since the value assigned to `ptr` is most probably the same as with `char *ptr = "hello"`. Rather `char *ptr = *(int *)"hello"` is what you want.

Comment: `char *ptr = *(int *)"hello"` doesn't compile for me.

Comment: That's no wonder, since according to ISO/IEC 9899 _A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic message ... if a ... translation unit contains a violation of any syntax rule or constraint_ and this initialization violates the constraints for assignment. Obviously the OP uses a non-conforming implementation.

Comment: And it's absolutely unclear what the OP really needs to do with that. I think to get the pattern that is build by a string literal, using an `int` is much more safe. The curiousness isn't forbidden.